# How can you use T-SQL to calcute time between event records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have simplified a problem that I have been asked to solve. Below I have a table similar to this.

```
id:          primary_key
person:      varchar(20)
logdatetime: datetime
description: varchar(30)
```

With this table, it stores data in the following manner.

```
id     person   logdatetime         description
-----------------------------------------------
4503   Joe      4/3/2018 11:00:00   Lunch
4504   Sam      4/3/2018 11:15:00   Lunch
4512   Joe      4/3/2018 12:05:00   Physics
4514   Sam      4/3/2018 12:05:00   Physics
4518   Sam      4/3/2018 13:05:00   Library
4521   Joe      4/3/2018 13:10:00   Language Arts
4522   Joe      4/3/2018 14:15:00   Day Complete
4526   Sam      4/3/2018 16:08:00   Day Complete
```

For each person, is it possible to use SQL to calculate the time spent in each class/activity. In the past, I have used a temporary table to link these events together, but this is a real time system where the data just keeps growing. The ideal result would be something like the following.  With the data structured like this, I can easily calculate the total time an event lasted.

```
id     person   logdatetime         enddatetime         description
-------------------------------------------------------------------
4503   Joe      4/3/2018 11:00:00   4/3/2018/12:05:00   Lunch
4504   Sam      4/3/2018 11:15:00   4/3/2018 12:05:00   Lunch
4512   Joe      4/3/2018 12:05:00   4/3/2018 13:10:00   Physics
4514   Sam      4/3/2018 12:05:00   4/3/2018 13:05:00   Physics
4518   Sam      4/3/2018 13:05:00   4/3/2018 16:08:00   Library
4521   Joe      4/3/2018 13:10:00   4/3/2018 14:15:00   Language Arts
4522   Joe      4/3/2018 14:15:00   null                Day Complete
4526   Sam      4/3/2018 16:08:00   null                Day Complete
```

What is a good SQL option to build a report that summarizes the time spent in s class/activity?  I don't have an option of changing how the data is stored in this table. This is for a SQL Server database.

Comment: Have a look at the `LAG`/`LEAD` functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql

Comment: Always use tags to specify the version of your software. different versions have different features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version using `LEAD()` (if you have 2012+)

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#x') is not null drop table #x
create table #x
(
    Id int, 
    Person varchar(5), 
    LogDateTime datetime, 
    Description varchar(20)
)
insert into #x
(
    id,
    person,
    logdatetime,
    description
) 
values
    (4503,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 11:00:00',   'Lunch'),
    (4504,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 11:15:00',   'Lunch'),
    (4512,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 12:05:00',   'Physics'),
    (4514,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 12:05:00',   'Physics'),
    (4518,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 13:05:00',   'Library'),
    (4521,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 13:10:00',   'Language Arts'),
    (4522,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 14:15:00',   'Day Complete'),
    (4526,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 16:08:00',   'Day Complete')

select 
    Id,
    Person,
    LogDateTime,
    EndDateTime = lead(LogDateTime, 1, null) over (partition by Person order by (Id)),
    Description
from #x
order by id
```

Comment: This answer is the most detailed and uses LEAD/LAG from MSSQL server. However another answer just uses SQL which I believe is not dependent on the database architecture and is a good answer too.

Answer (score 2):

let's try it with Joe

```
--just to get some sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x
CREATE TABLE #x(id INT, person VARCHAR(5), logdatetime DATETIME, description VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #x(id,person,logdatetime,description) VALUES
(4503,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 11:00:00',   'Lunch'),
(4504,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 11:15:00',   'Lunch'),
(4512,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 12:05:00',   'Physics'),
(4514,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 12:05:00',   'Physics'),
(4518,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 13:05:00',   'Library'),
(4521,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 13:10:00',   'Language Arts'),
(4522,   'Joe',      '4/3/2018 14:15:00',   'Day Complete'),
(4526,   'Sam',      '4/3/2018 16:08:00',   'Day Complete')

--actual query
SELECT
      description,
      a.logdatetime AS 'Start',
      (SELECT TOP 1 b.logdatetime FROM #x AS b WHERE b.person=a.person AND b.id>a.id ORDER BY b.id) AS 'End',
      DATEDIFF(minute,a.logdatetime,
      (SELECT TOP 1 b.logdatetime FROM #x AS b WHERE b.person=a.person AND b.id>a.id ORDER BY b.id) ) AS 'TimeDiff(Min)'
FROM #x AS a
WHERE a.person='Joe'
```

output

```
description   Start                      End                   TimeDiff(Min)
Lunch         2018-04-03 11:00:00.000   2018-04-03 12:05:00.000   65
Physics       2018-04-03 12:05:00.000   2018-04-03 13:10:00.000   65
Language Arts 2018-04-03 13:10:00.000   2018-04-03 14:15:00.000   65
Day Complete  2018-04-03 14:15:00.000   NULL                      NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, person, logdatetime, 
    LEAD(logdatetime, 1,null) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY id) AS  enddatetime, description
FROM test
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the timespent in minutes using lead

```
SELECT Person, description, logdatetime, 
CASE WHEN TimeSpent < 0 THEN 0 ELSE TimeSpent END AS TimeSpent
 FROM (SELECT Person, description, logdatetime,
 (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,logdatetime,LEAD(logdatetime,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY id))) AS TimeSpent  FROM Tempx) AS SEL
```